# Что обозначает конструкция &имя_структуры::член_структуры?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Допустим, имеется структура Plan. в ней есть поле char kod (не static).
Что обозначает следующая запись:

```
&Plan::Kod
```

Хочу отметить, я не ошибся. & именно перед названием структуры, а не перед объектом типа Plan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возвращается тип, устроенный на усмотрение компилятора так, чтобы он идентифицировал любое поле класса без использования имён, которые придумал программист. Практически обычно содержит в себе смещение в байтах этого элемента и ещё служебную информацию.

```
class   Plan {
public  :    
    int i ;
    int j ;
} ;
# include <iostream>

int main ( ) {        
    auto sm = & Plan :: i ;
    Plan p ;
    p .* sm = 1 ; // p . i = 1 ;
    sm = & Plan :: j ;
    p .* sm = 2 ; // p . j = 2 ;
    std :: cout << "p = { .i = " << p . i <<
      ", .j = " << p . j << " }" << std::endl; 
}
```

---

```
p = { .i = 1, .j = 2 }
```

Обращение к полю **конкретного** объекта по это структуре реализуется с помощью оператора `.*` ;

---

*Тип его без использования `auto` можно написать так :*

```
int Plan :: * sm = & Plan :: i ;
```

*В английских текстах это называется указателями, хотя в скобках уточняют, что это **не** указатели. И использовать можно только относительно фактического объекта.*

Comment: Это именно что указатель, разновидность "указатель на член структуры"

Comment: Хотя по смыслу это смещение, тем не менее в стандарте (и во всех учебниках) он назван именно указателем: "Pointers to data members" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members

Comment: @Chorkov это даже по смыслу не смещение, потому что смещение - число, а тут другой тип

Comment: Мне это очень напоминает функцию `offsetof` - что в переводе как раз и есть смещение. @Pavel Mayorov

Comment: @AlexGlebe вот только offsetof именно что возвращает число, а тип `T::*` числом не является

Comment: @AlexGlebe , подскажите, возможна ли разница при работе с этим функционалом в visual studio 2010 и 2015?  Это работало как нужно в студии 10го года, но не в студии 15го года.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Тип у него другой, но если посмотреть содержимое (`reinterpret_cast`-ом, например), то внутри почти наверняка будет смещение.

Comment: *"Это работало как нужно в студии 10го года, но не в студии 15го года."* - нужно задать это как полный вопрос со всеми тонкостями и программой. Угадать не смогу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat именно что почти